# How to do Matrix Addition with CUDA C

Tags: c, matrix, cuda, nvidia

I am writing a simpled code about the addition of the elements of 2 matrices A and B; the code is quite simple and it is inspired on the example given in chapter 2 of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 2

__global__ void MatAdd(int A[][N], int B[][N], int C[][N]){
           int i = threadIdx.x;
           int j = threadIdx.y;

           C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
       }


int main(){

int A[N][N] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int B[N][N] = {{5,6},{7,8}};
int C[N][N] = {{0,0},{0,0}};    

int (*pA)[N], (*pB)[N], (*pC)[N];

cudaMalloc((void**)&pA, (N*N)*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**)&pB, (N*N)*sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**)&pC, (N*N)*sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpy(pA, A, (N*N)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(pB, B, (N*N)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(pC, C, (N*N)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

int numBlocks = 1;
dim3 threadsPerBlock(N,N);
MatAdd<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(A,B,C);

cudaMemcpy(C, pC, (N*N)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

int i, j; printf("C = \n");
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<N;j++){
        printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

cudaFree(pA); 
cudaFree(pB); 
cudaFree(pC);

printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

when i run it i keep getting the initial matrix C = [0 0 ; 0 0] instead of the addition of the elements(i,j) of the 2 matrices A and B; i have previously done another example about the addition of the elements of two arrays and it seems to work fine; however this time i don't know why it does not work.

I believe there's something wrong with the cudaMalloc command by i don't really know what else could it be.

Any ideas?

Comment: start by adding [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) to your code.  Your method of creating 2D matrices on the device won't work as-is.  Because of the difficulty associated with creating 2D matrices on the device, it's frequently suggested that you avoid it and flatten your matrices to 1D, and use index/pointer arithmetic to simulate 2D access.  (your pointer allocations for `pA`, etc. are basically 1D at the moment anyway.)

Comment: Your comment helped a lot mr. @JackOLantern

Comment: Could you try `MatAdd<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(pA,pB,pC);` ?

Comment: @francis what you just wrote seems to be the correct answer!! however i still don't understand why the values contained in A, B and C shouldn't be mapped to the MatAdd function...

Comment: since matrix addition is just position by position, can't you just deal with a 1d array?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MatAdd<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(pA,pB,pC);` instead of `MatAdd<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(A,B,C);` solves the problem.

The reason is that `A,B` and `C` are allocated on the CPU, while `pA,pB` and `pC` are allocated of the GPU, using `CudaMalloc()`. Once `pA,pB` and `pC` are allocated, the values are sent from the CPU to GPU by `cudaMemcpy(pA, A, (N*N)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);`

Then, the addition is performed on the GPU, that is with `pA,pB` and `pC`. To use `printf`, the result `pC` is sent from the GPU to the CPU via `cudaMemcpy(C, pC, (N*N)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);`

Think as if the CPU cannot see `pA` and the GPU cannot see `A`.

Comment: Now that i read this is so much clear... thank you very much for helping me out!!!